# Plotting dictionary values into multi_line / timeseries Bokeh chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, bokeh

*Note from maintainers: This question is about the obsolete `bokeh.charts` API removed years ago. For information on plotting with modern Boheh, including timseries, see:*

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html

---

---

I have a defined dictionary of values where key is a date in a form of string and values are an array of floats.

Dictionary looks like this:

```
dict = 
{'2017-03-23': [1.07874, 1.07930, 1.07917, 1.07864,], 
'2017-03-27': [1.08382, 1.08392, 1.08410, 1.08454], 
'2017-03-24': [1.07772, 1.07721, 1.07722, 1.07668]}
```

I want to display each date as a separate line on a Bokeh line_chart. Since the dates interval will change over time, I do not want to simply define p1.line, p2.line, p3.line (a static set) for each date because the amount of plotted dates will vary over time.

I have tried to follow tutorials here: http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.9.3/docs/user_guide/charts.html but I keep struggling and getting errors.

Here is my code:

```
#input dates at this occasion
dates = ['2017-03-27','2017-03-24', '2017-03-23']

#dataframe is taken from input and contains columns date,time,close and other columns that I am not using
df

#I create a dictionary of dataframe in the structure described above
dict = {k: list(v) for k, v in df.groupby("date")["close"]}

#i want to plot chart
output_file("chart2.html")
p = figure(title="Dates line charts", x_axis_label='Index', y_axis_label='Price')
p = TimeSeries(dict, index='Index', legend=True, title="FX", ylabel='Price Prices')
show(p)
```

I am getting this error:

*AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'index' to Chart, possible attributes are above, background_fill_alpha, background_fill_color, below, border_fill_alpha, border_fill_color, css_classes, disabled, extra_x_ranges, extra_y_ranges, h_symmetry, height, hidpi, inner_height, inner_width, js_callbacks, left, lod_factor, lod_interval, lod_threshold, lod_timeout, min_border, min_border_bottom, min_border_left, min_border_right, min_border_top, name, outline_line_alpha, outline_line_cap, outline_line_color, outline_line_dash, outline_line_dash_offset, outline_line_join, outline_line_width, plot_height, plot_width, renderers, right, sizing_mode, tags, title, title_location, tool_events, toolbar, toolbar_location, toolbar_sticky, v_symmetry, webgl, width, x_mapper_type, x_range, xlabel, xscale, y_mapper_type, y_range, ylabel or yscale*

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

*Note from maintainers: This question is about the obsolete `bokeh.charts` API removed years ago. For information on plotting with modern Boheh, including timseries, see:*

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html

---

---

You are looking at very old documentation (0.9.3). The latest documentation (0.12.4) for bokeh Timeseries [can be found here](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.12.14/docs/reference/charts.html#timeseries).

As you can see, Timeseries no longer accepts an `index` parameter. The available parameters are

> **data** (list(list), numpy.ndarray, pandas.DataFrame, list(pd.Series)) –
> a 2d data source with columns of data for each stepped line.
>
> **x** (str or
> list(str), optional) – specifies variable(s) to use for x axis
>
> **y** (str
> or list(str), optional) – specifies variable(s) to use for y axis
>
> **builder_type** (str or Builder, optional) – the type of builder to use
> to produce the renderers. Supported options are ‘line’, ‘step’, or
> ‘point’.

Just follow the example given in the most recent documentation and you should not run into the same problem.